# blueprintjs keep content mounted in tabs

Tags: tabs, blueprintjs

I am not sure if this is blueprintjs specific behaviour (new to react as well), but I cannot find a way to keep content loaded in a tab once rendered. I think "keep mounted" is the react terminology.

```
<Tabs id="mainNavbar" selectedTabId={this.state.mainNavbarTabId} renderActiveTabPanelOnly={true}
     onChange={this.handleNavbarTabChange}>
  <Tab id="tabOne" title="Tab One" panel={<TabOnePanel/>}/>
  <Tab id="tabTwo" title="Tab Two" panel={<TabTwoPanel/>}/>
</Tabs>
```

Is the technique to use a "alreadyRendered" flag in the render()? Please could you suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc, you should set `renderActiveTabPanelOnly` to `false` (which is the default value). That will keep it mounted. According to the doc:

```
"Whether inactive tab panels should be removed from the DOM and unmounted in React.
This can be a performance enhancement when rendering many complex panels, 
but requires careful support for unmounting and remounting."
```

[ https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/tabs ]

Comment: Oh, I just noticed how old is this... probably found the answer yourself :-)

Comment: No I haven't solved. Will give it a go. It's a long term project that still isn't complete - as you do :) Thank you